# Having some difficulties with firebase in a React Native application - Warning: Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm building out the messaging component for a react native app using firebase & gifted chat. I'm not super strong with React, and having some issues getting the messages i'm sending in the chat to form unique (private) chats in the firebase db. ie if I change the user object, I want that to set a new unique chat ID and therefore each chat with each contact would be private (and persistent), but it's not working out like that for the moment.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '12345',
  authDomain: '12345',
  projectId: '12345',
  storageBucket: '12345',
  messagingSenderId: '12345',
  appId: '12345',
  measurementId: '12345',
};

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

function MessagesHomeScreen() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [contact, setContact] = useState(null);
  const [chatID, setChatID] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    readUser();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    uniqueChatID();
  }, [contact]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMessage = async () => {
      const unsubscribe = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('messages')
        .doc(chatID)
        .collection('chats')
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const messagesFirestore = querySnapshot
            .docChanges()
            .filter(({ type }) => type === 'added')
            .map(({ doc }) => {
              message = doc.data();
              return { ...message, createdAt: message.createdAt.toDate() };
            })
            .sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.getTime() - a.createdAt.getTime());
          appendMessages(messagesFirestore);
        });
      return () => unsubscribe();
    };
    fetchMessage();
  }, [chatID]);

  const readUser = async () => {
    const fetchUser = await userInfoStorage.getUserInfo();
    const userObj = JSON.parse(fetchUser);
    const user = { _id: userObj.uuid, name: userObj.first_name };
    setUser(user);
  };

  const appendMessages = useCallback(
    (messages) => {
      setMessages((previousMessages) =>
        GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages)
      );
    },
    [messages]
  );

  const handleSend = async (messages) => {
    const writes = messages.map((m) =>
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('messages')
        .doc(chatID)
        .collection('chats')
        .add(m)
    );
    await Promise.all(writes);
  };

  const uniqueChatID = () => {
    const userUUID = user?._id;
    const contactUUID = contact;
    const chatID = [];
    chatID.push(userUUID);
    chatID.push(contactUUID);
    chatID.sort();
    const chatIDString = chatID.join('-');
    return setChatID(chatIDString);
  };

  if (!contact) {
    return <ContactList updateParent={(contact) => setContact(contact)} />;
  }

  if (user && contact) {
    return (
      <>
        <GiftedChat
          messages={messages}
          user={user}
          onSend={handleSend}
          scrollToBottom={true}
        />
        <Button
          title={'Chat With Another Contact'}
          onPress={() => setContact(null)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default MessagesHomeScreen;
```

And the error is the following

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `e26d5caf-e048-4162-9b43-17aa6b554b75`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: Can you share with us the code of `GiftedChat` and `ContactList`. For me it looks like the error comes from one of those.